# Interaction between two separate Windows in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scope

How can I access a variable in `MainWindow.xaml.cs` that is defined as `public` from `Window1.xaml.cs`?

I thought that if a variable is defined that way I will be able to access it from anywhere. What am I missing here?

Comment: Why do you need that? You should use events to decouple the two. Raise an event in `Window1` and handle that in `MainWindow`.

Comment: @MariusBancila For example I have `public double MyVar` in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`, and now I want to use it in `Window1.xaml.cs`. How can I raise an event to do this? Can you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you don't care about MVVM, then all you need is an instance of `MainWindow`. Give it to `Window1` somehow (`Window1` constructor with parameter,  `Window1` method/property, `static` class somewhere to hold it, etc.) and access like this: `instance.MyVar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought that if a variable is defined that way I will be able to access it from anywhere

Unless the variable is both public and static, you can't access it from almost anywhere coz that should be accessed based on a certain instance of an object.

If you wanna access a variable from any window, either make it static or call it based on an instance of that window like

```
Window1 win = new Window1();
win.Variablex = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I get to mix these concepts now and then :(